# using the right grep option

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, grep

I need help with setting up the correct grep command in shell script.
What I am currently using is:

```
grep '[A-Za-z]|' words
```

(I'm using a massive text file with tons of words in it.  It's the size of a few dictionaries.)

The problem is that I have to filter out single letter words (except for `a`, `i` & `o`), and the words cannot be less than 2 characters, and they must contain a vowel.

I am unsure on how to do this. I'm assuming you use the "or" expression. What I have tried to use and failed was:

```
grep '[A-Za-z]|[a,i,o]'
```

and then I have no idea how to force it to match 2 characters.

Comment: Look into "anchoring" your regex

Comment: And don't use the or unless you're willing to accept only one side of it with nothing from the other as a valid match.

Comment: The character class `[a,i,o]` is equivalent to `[aio,]`; you don't need the comma.

Comment: Have you run `grep --help`?  You're on Linux, so you'll have GNU `grep` and it supports the `--help` option.  You should review the options available.  Some of `-v`, `-i`, `-E`, `-o`, `-w` may be helpful — there may be others too (`-P` perhaps).  When you say 'filter out single-letter words', do you mean you want to select only `a`, `i`, `o` as single-letter words (with case-insensitive matching), and otherwise accept words which are two or more characters long, and which contain at least one vowel? Do you want to see only the words or do you want to see the line in which the word is embedded?

Comment: What is the format of the `words` file?  One word per line?  Is there punctuation to deal with?  Digits?  Spaces?  Is "`don't`" a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to select valid words, case-insensitively, where a valid word can be:

- a single-letter word "a", "i", "o"
- a two-or-more letter word starting with a vowel
- a two-or-more letter word ending with a vowel
- a three-or-more letter word with a vowel in the middle

then you can use:

```
grep -Eiwo -e '[aio]|[aeiouy][a-z]+|[a-z]+[aeiouy]|[a-z]+[aeiouy][a-z]+'
```

Options:

- `-E` extended regular expressions (using `|` and `+`)
- `-i` case-insensitive
- `-w` match word boundaries
- `-o` output only the matches
- `-e regexp` — the regular expression to match

Regular expression:

- 4 alternative terms separated by `|`
- select single-letter words
- select words starting with a vowel and containing one or more letters after the leading vowel
- select words ending with a vowel and containing one or more letters before the trailing vowel
- select words starting with one or more letters followed by a vowel and then one or more letters.

These patterns are not mutually exclusive.  For example, given the input word `oboe`, all three of the multi-letter patterns match it — only the single-letter pattern fails (it does have four letters, after all).  However, only one of the patterns needs to match it; the others don't alter the output for that word.

Here is some text (reputedly from "Dracula"):

```
 "Then he spoke to me mockingly, 'And so you, like the others, would play
your brains against mine. You would help these men to hunt me and
frustrate me in my designs! You know now, and they know in part already,
and will know in full before long, what it is to cross my path. They
should have kept their energies for use closer to home. Whilst they
played wits against me--against me who commanded nations, and intrigued
for them, and fought for them, hundreds of years before they were
born--I was countermining them. And you, their best beloved one, are now
to me, flesh of my flesh; blood of my blood; kin of my kin; my bountiful
wine-press for a while; and shall be later on my companion and my
helper. You shall be avenged in turn; for not one of them but shall
minister to your needs. But as yet you are to be punished for what you
have done. You have aided in thwarting me; now you shall come to my
call. When my brain says "Come!" to you, you shall cross land or sea to
do my bidding; and to that end this!' With that he pulled open his
shirt, and with his long sharp nails opened a vein in his breast. When
the blood began to spurt out, he took my hands in one of his, holding
them tight, and with the other, my neck and pressed my mouth to
the wound, so that I must either suffocate or swallow some of the---- Oh
my God! my God! what have I done? What have I done to deserve such a
fate, I who have tried to walk in meekness and righteousness all my
days. God pity me! Look down on a poor soul in worse than mortal peril;
and in mercy pity those to whom she is dear!" Then she began to rub her
lips as though to cleanse them from pollution.

"Oh, no, not distressed me," she replied, "but I have been more touched
than I can say by your grief. That is a wonderful machine, but it is
cruelly true. It told me, in its very tones, the anguish of your heart.
It was like a soul crying out to Almighty God. No one must hear them
spoken ever again! See, I have tried to be useful. I have copied out the
words on my typewriter, and none other need now hear your heart beat, as
I did."
```

This is the sorted, case-insensitive list of words selected from this text by the `grep` command above, presented in columnar format:

```
a             again         against       aided         all           Almighty      already
And           anguish       are           as            avenged       be            beat
been          before        began         beloved       best          bidding       blood
born          bountiful     brain         brains        breast        but           by
call          can           cleanse       closer        come          commanded     companion
copied        countermining cross         cruelly       crying        days          dear
deserve       designs       did           distressed    do            done          down
either        end           energies      ever          fate          flesh         for
fought        from          frustrate     full          God           grief         hands
have          he            hear          heart         help          helper        her
his           holding       home          hundreds      hunt          I             in
intrigued     is            it            its           kept          kin           know
land          later         like          lips          long          Look          machine
me            meekness      men           mercy         mine          minister      mockingly
more          mortal        mouth         must          my            nails         nations
neck          need          needs         no            none          not           now
of            Oh            on            one           open          opened        or
other         others        out           part          path          peril         pity
play          played        pollution     poor          press         pressed       pulled
punished      replied       righteousness rub           say           says          sea
See           shall         sharp         she           shirt         should        so
some          soul          spoke         spoken        spurt         such          suffocate
swallow       than          that          the           their         them          Then
these         they          this          those         though        thwarting     tight
to            told          tones         took          touched       tried         true
turn          typewriter    use           useful        vein          very          walk
was           were          what          When          while         Whilst        who
whom          will          wine          With          wits          wonderful     words
worse         would         wound         years         yet           you           your
```

Comment: thank you brother i have no clue how you figured that one out but thank god you came across my question!

Answer (score -1):

I think the following regex could do the job:

```
^[^aio]{1}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$
```

Comment: it doesnt work i re-tried  grep '[A-Za-z]^[^aio]{1}$'

Comment: sorry, try: ^[^aio]{1}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$

Comment: Why `0-9`?  How does the `{2,}` part ensure there is at least one vowel?